# Words are being covered by something

Tags: bug, design

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

The top portion of the words is being covered by something. The 'FEATURED ON META' block is showing the same problem on Mathematics and Physics site and not on other sites. But the top bar which has 'Questions', 'Tags', 'Users', etc. is showing the problem only on this site. Why is this happening and how do I correct it? I am using Firefox 60.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I can't see your image but I can't repro it based on your description on Chrome twins. On Android and Windows 10 PC.

Comment: @M.A.R.ಠ_ಠ Can you see the.two screenshots posted? https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3mi4.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocCaC.png

Comment: Nope. I mean, the problem isn't on your side.

Comment: The problem is absent on Firefox 58, 59 and 60 (all on Windows 10)

Comment: @GaurangTandon I guess I'll have to ask on AskUbuntu because I'm facing the same problem on some non SE sites too.

Comment: It doesn't happen with Firefox 60 on a Mac.